# Fetch Billing phone number Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phone-number

i have a code

```
//first check if my_custom_users_list is defined before or not.
if(!function_exists('my_custom_users_list')){
    //function that runs when shortcode is called
    function my_custom_users_list() {
        $args = array(); //define arguments if you need
        $users = get_users($args);

        $listHtml = '<ul>';
        foreach($users as $user){
            $listHtml .= '<li>'
                         . 'ID: '.$user->data->ID."<br />"
                         . 'Username: '.$user->data->user_login."<br />"
                         . 'Nice Name: '.$user->data->user_nicename."<br />"
                         . 'Display Name: '.$user->data->display_name."<br />"
                         . 'Email: '.$user->data->user_email."<br />"
                         . 'URL (website): '.$user->data->user_url."<br />"
                         . 'Registration Date: '.$user->data->user_registered."<br />"
                         . 'User Phone number: '.$user->data->billing_phone."<br />"
                         . '</li>';
        }
        $listHtml .= '</ul>';

        return $listHtml;
    }

}

//register my-users-list shortcode
function register_my_users_list_shortcode(){
    add_shortcode('my-users-list', 'my_custom_users_list');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_users_list_shortcode' );

//to test the shortcode, uncomment next line:
/*echo do_shortcode('[my-users-list]');*/
```

The code works, but not showing phone number
I tried with meta phone_number also, but now showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get user info like ID, username etc. without using data inside your loop example:
// Get User ID - you can use $user->ID
// Get User Email - you can user $user->user_email

For your question about getting phone number you need to use get_user_meta function. If you use woocommerce and you want to get the billing phone number you can get it using this:
get_user_meta($user->ID, 'billing_phone')

Comment: . 'Billing phone: '.$user->billing_phone."<br />"

Worked well. Thank you.